# How to make a date column in a table that automatically fills itself out when a new item is added to the table?

Tags: excel

E.g.
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRtlw.png)

When I enter a new row the previous dates should not update.

Answer (score 0):

How are you writing in the dates in the first place?

Enter the date into the new rows as a value. Don't use the TODAY() function as this will always change to the date as of opening the worksheet.

Comment: I'm using the DD/MM/YY format which causes no trouble at the moment but it would be more convenient not to have to manually do it every time.

Comment: Consider writing a VBA script that gets today's date and saves it in the row as a string/static value